# fullcalendar/django refetchEvents() not works or can not uderstand how it works

Tags: django, fullcalendar

I have a django application with this model.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
class Events(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
start = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
end = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
return self.name
```

this view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from mycalendars.models import Events

def calendar(request):
all_events = Events.objects.all()
context = {
"events":all_events,
}
return render(request,'calendar.html',context)

def add_event(request):
start = request.GET.get("start", None)
end = request.GET.get("end", None)
title = request.GET.get("title", None)
event = Events(title=str(title), start=start, end=end)
event.save()
data = {}
return JsonResponse(data)

def remove(request):
id = request.GET.get("id", None)
event = Events.objects.get(id=id)
event.delete()
data = {}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

this urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from mycalendars import views

urlpatterns = [
url('^calendar', views.calendar, name='calendar'),
url('^add_event$', views.add_event, name='add_event'),
url('^remove', views.remove, name='remove'),
]
```

in templates I have the calendar.html with all the full calendar like this:

```
<html><head>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
var Draggable = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable;
var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
new Draggable(containerEl, {
itemSelector: '.fc-event',
eventData: function(eventEl) {
return {
title: eventEl.innerText,
duration: '24:00',
};
}
});
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
events: [
{% for event in events %}
{
title: "{{ event.title}}",
start: '{{ event.start|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
end: '{{ event.end|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
id: '{{ event.id }}',
},
{% endfor %}
],
plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
},
editable: true,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
eventLimit: true,
droppable: true,
eventRender: function(info) {
var descrip = info.event.title;
if (descrip.indexOf('Birthday') !== -1) {
info.el.firstChild.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
} else if (descrip.indexOf('Medical') !== -1) {
info.el.firstChild.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blu;");
} else if (descrip.indexOf('Work') !== -1) {
info.el.firstChild.setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;");
}
eventReceive: function (info) {
var title = info.event.title;
var start = moment(info.event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
var end = moment(info.event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '/add_event',
data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end},
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
calendar.refetchEvents();
alert("Added Successfully");
},
failure: function (data) {
alert('There is a problem!!!');
}
});
},
eventClick: function (info) {
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?")) {
var id = info.event.id;
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '/remove',
data: {'id': id},
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
calendar.refetchEvents();
alert('Event Removed');
},
failure: function (data) {
alert('There is a problem!!!');
}
});
}
},
});
calendar.render();
});
</script>
<style>
#external-events {
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
width: 150px;
padding: 0 10px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background: #eee;
}

.demo-topbar + #external-events {
top: 60px;
}

#external-events .fc-event {
margin: 1em 0;
cursor: move;
}

#calendar-container {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
margin-left: 200px;
}

#calendar {
max-width: 900px;
margin: 20px auto;
}

</style>
</head><body>
<div id='external-events'>
<p>
<strong>Type of event:</strong>
</p>
<div class='fc-event' style="background-color:red">Birthday</div>
<div class='fc-event' style="background-color:blu">Medical</div>
<div class='fc-event' style="background-color:green">Work</div>
</div>
<div id='calendar-container'>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Now my question, when I drag and drop the label work, medical or birthday into the calendar this will ben render correctly but if I try to canel one with the event click on one of thoose I get an error. I notice the events will not be updated ( I have the events in my daabase, but non in current page) if I reload the page the new events will be loaded.
I read a lot of posts said my events is static but they are not static after $ajax get /add_event or /remove the data should be reloaded with the calendar.refetchEvents() . I tried to add an eventSource, I tried to have e new view in my djago view.py with list_event with JSON events, but none of those works.
Any hints is welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: _"I read a lot of posts said my events is static"_ ...and they were correct, at least from fullCalendar's point of view.  `events: [
{% for event in events %}
{
title: "{{ event.title}}",
start: '{{ event.start|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
end: '{{ event.end|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
id: '{{ event.id }}',
},
{% endfor %}
],` will create a hard-coded list of event data which is then given to fullCalendar (you can see this if you inspect your final rendered page in your browser using its View Source feature).

Comment: This is just a list of data. There is no information given to fullCalendar about where those events came from, or - more importantly - how to find an updated list of events in future. So when you run `refetchEvents`, what do you expect fullCalendar to do? It cannot re-run your python code to get more events, because it doesn't know anything about it.

Comment: If you want refetchEvents to work, you have to use a dynamic event source. This involves telling fullCalendar the URL on your server where it can send a request to download the latest event data. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed for more details.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all I found a solution:
I put in javascript:

```
events: {
                url :'/all_events',
        },
```

and in views.py and urls.py I add

```
def all_events(request):
    data = Events.objects.filter().values('id', 'title', 'start', 'end')
    json_str = simplejson.dumps(list(data), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(json_str , content_type='application/json')
```

and

```
... 
  url('^all_events', views.all_events, name='all_events'),
```

Now the fetchEvents is working.